# How do I fix these M4 macro errors?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, mate, autoconf

I am trying to compile [mate-desktop](https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-desktop)
but when I run `./autogen.sh` the script terminates with these errors

```
Checking for required M4 macros...
  libtool.m4 not found
  glib-gettext.m4 not found
  intltool.m4 not found
  pkg.m4 not found
  gtk-doc.m4 not found
  yelp.m4 not found
***Error***: some autoconf macros required to build mate-desktop
  were not found in your aclocal path, or some forbidden
  macros were found.  Perhaps you need to adjust your
  ACLOCAL_FLAGS?
```

What do I need to do to get rid of these errors? I tired installing the latest versions of inittool, glib, gtk, yelp, etc... but I still get the macros errors.

Comment: Do the listed macros exist (in /usr/share/aclocal by default, I think) and the autogen script is simply not finding them - or are they actually missing?

Comment: @steeldriver yes, the macros are in that directory, what should I do?

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't be finding macros in (what I believe is) the *standard* directory, however you could try `ACLOCAL_FLAGS="-I /usr/share/aclocal" ./autogen.sh`. If you installed mate-common in /usr/local you may need to add that as well i.e. `ACLOCAL_FLAGS="-I /usr/share/aclocal -I /usr/local/share/aclocal" ./autogen.sh`

Comment: You are missing the development packages for some of the dependencies. You'll need to install the appropriate -dev packages that provide those files.

Comment: @steeldriver That did it! Thanks! If you want to mark that in as answer I'll give it to you and this question can be solved!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, `aclocal` *should* search the /usr/share/aclocal directory for macros - as indicated by the `--print-ac-dir` option:

```
$ aclocal --print-ac-dir 
/usr/share/aclocal
```

However, if for some reason yours is failing to search there, you can add an explicit search path via the `ACLOCAL_FLAGS` environment variable e.g.

```
ACLOCAL_FLAGS="-I /usr/share/aclocal" ./autogen.sh
```

Note that both the `mate-common` and `gtk-doc` installations from github default to installing their m4 macros into `/usr/local/share/aclocal` which isn't searched by default even with a "working" `aclocal`; you can add this path the same way i.e.

```
ACLOCAL_FLAGS="-I /usr/share/aclocal -I /usr/local/share/aclocal" ./autogen.sh
```